# How to set a border on a Vaadin component?

Tags: vaadin

I would like to programmatically set a border around a Form component in Java. How can I do this without having to edit the css style sheet?

Comment: Similar: [*Vaadin Grid layout borders*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32967850/642706)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could wrap the form with a Panel component, which has a border defined already. Otherwise, not much alternatives than just using CSS.

One option, if you wish to stay inside the server environment, is to use the CSSInject add-on and add the border using that (you still need to write CSS, but you can do it on the server in a Java file and not inside a regular CSS file).

Comment: One problem I have is that every time I removeComponent and then addComponent with Internet Explorer 9 then the top border dissappears from the panel... works ok in Firefox, so I wanted to programmatically add the top border

Comment: That sounds strange, the border shouldn't disappear. Can you post a code sample?

Answer (score 7):

## Vaadin Flow — `Style::set` to specify CSS

In [Vaadin Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin#Vaadin_Flow) (Vaadin versions 10 and later), you can conveniently **set CSS for a widget or layout programmatically**. No need to edit separate CSS files, even though styling with CSS files is the recommended way.

1. On your widget/layout, call [`getStyle`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.6/com/vaadin/flow/component/HasStyle.html#getStyle--) to retrieve the [`Style`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.6/com/vaadin/flow/dom/Style.html) object.
2. On that `Style` object, call [`set`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.0.6/com/vaadin/flow/dom/Style.html#set-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) to pass the name and value of your CSS property.

For example, I find setting a [bright colored](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#X11_color_names) border on my nested layouts quite helpful for debugging.

```
myVerticalLayout.getStyle().set( "border" , "6px dotted DarkOrange" ) ;
```

You can see this in action with this screenshot on [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57540032/642706) to another Vaadin question here:

[image: screenshot of a layout with an obnoxious orange border added for debugging purposes]