# Vaadin Grid layout borders

Tags: css, vaadin

I have three form with few `TextField` in my `View` (`GridLayout`), I need to designate each form with black line borders. How Can I do that. Do I need include css? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code you are working with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to add a style to the GridLayout.

```
final GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
// Add stuff to it ...
gridLayout.addStyleName("your-css-tag");
```

In your theme css (in my workspace webapp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/mytheme.scss):

```
.your-css-tag {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: black;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

You may need a rebuild of your project, to incorporate the CSS. In Maven, that means executing the `Lifecycle` tasks `clean` and `install`.

For more information, see the manual chapter on *Themes*.

- [Version 7, Themes](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/themes/themes-overview.html)
- [Version 8, Themes](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/themes/themes-overview.html)
- [Version 10, Themes](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/theme/theming-overview.html)

Comment: Thnak you! Seems legit, I will try it.

Comment: I believe you will want to call [`.addStyleName`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.1/8.1.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#addStyleName-java.lang.String-) rather than [`.setStyleName`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.1/8.1.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#setStyleName-java.lang.String-) as the `set` method wipes out other previously assigned styles.

Comment: You may need to rebuild your project in such a way as to trigger the CSS compilation process. For a Maven-based project, that might mean running the Lifecycle items `clean` and `install`.