# Why does the button protrude from the layout in Vaadin Flow 14?

Tags: java, layout, flexbox, vaadin, vaadin14

So I have a

```java
var layout = new HorizontalLayout();
layout.add(confirmButton);
layout.add(cancelButton);
layout.getElement().getStyle().set("flex-direction", "row-reverse");
```

This results in a layout that is too short to contain the buttons,

which in turn leads to an unwanted horizontal scrollbar when I expand the `layout` to full width.

How do I keep the buttons within the layout?

[image]

**UPDATE**

This is with

```
Vaadin 14.1.16
Java 11 (OpenJDK 11.0.6)
on whatever tomcat comes with Spring Boot 2.2.4.RELEASE
in Chrome 80.0.3987.106
on Linux (Ubuntu 19.10 derivate)
```

Comment: My _guess_ here is around the fact that the layout gets confused with the spacing between the elements and/or box-sizing. If you really just want move the buttons to the right, you can also add them in screen order and then put a `margin-left: auto` on the cancelButton.

Comment: I confirmed your issue. Without setting the reverse direction, the buttons are contained within the layout, as expected. Add the reverse direction and the "Save" button is hanging outside the layout to the right, as your report here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Apparently a bug

I tried your code, and verified the issue. Seems to be a bug. So I opened an [issue ticket, # 7738](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/7738).

I added a colored dotted border to the layout to show what is happening. See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58111262/642706) of mine for adding a border to a layout in Vaadin Flow.

Here is a complete example app.

By the way, I suspect you can skip your call to `getElement`. The `HorizontalLayout` class offers a `getStyle` method itself, which apparently is a convenience method that accomplishes the same end. Your issue appears with and without calling `getElement`.

```
package work.basil.example;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.CssImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.HorizontalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;


/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route ( "" )
//@PWA(name = "Project Base for Vaadin", shortName = "Project Base")
@CssImport ( "./styles/shared-styles.css" )
@CssImport ( value = "./styles/vaadin-text-field-styles.css", themeFor = "vaadin-text-field" )
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout
{

    public MainView ( )
    {
        HorizontalLayout plain = this.makeLayout();

        HorizontalLayout reversed = this.makeLayout();
        reversed.getStyle().set( "flex-direction" , "row-reverse" );

        this.add( plain , reversed );
    }

    private HorizontalLayout makeLayout ( )
    {
        // Widgets
        Button confirmButton = new Button( "Save" );
        Button cancelButton = new Button( "Cancel" );

        // Arrange
        HorizontalLayout layout = new HorizontalLayout();
        layout.add( confirmButton );
        layout.add( cancelButton );

        // Style
        layout.getStyle().set( "border" , "4px dotted DarkOrange" );

        return layout;
    }
}
```

And a screenshot. Running Vaadin 14.1.18, Java 13, macOS Mojave, using Jetty server within IntelliJ 2019.3.3. Client is Microsoft Edge, version 80.0.361.62. Similar result in Safari Technology Preview version Release 101 (Safari 13.2, WebKit 14610.1.3.1), and in Firefox Developer Edition 74.0b9 (64-bit).

[image: screenshot of two horizontal layouts, one of which has the second button hanging outside its bounds]

## Workaround

For now, abandon use of Flexbox reverse order. Write conditional code that adds your buttons in the appropriate order.